# How do I get the key=value pair in the url?

Tags: jsp

I have this code:

```
while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) { 
    String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();
    String paramValue = request.getHeader(paramName);

    out.println(paramName + "=" + paramValue);
}
```

that produces:

```
course_code3=null schedule_no3=null course_sched3=null
```

when the url contains the following:

```
pntc_confirmrsvd.jsp?course_sched3=3&course_code3=CSM101&schedule_no3=201403
```

Why am I not getting the key=value pair in the url? What wrong with the code above? Any help will be really appreciated as I've been stumped by this for 3 hours already. :(

What I actually need to do is something like this:

```
while(paramNames.hasMoreElements())
{ 
    String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();
    String paramValue = request.getHeader(paramName);

    if (paramName.contains("course_code"))
    {
        course_code = paramValue;
    }
    else if (paramName.contains("schedule_no"))
    {
        schedule_no = paramValue;
    }
    else if (paramName.contains("course_sched"))
    {
        course_sched = paramValue;
    }

    out.println("Course: " + course_code + " ,Schedule: " + schedule_no + " , Item: "+course_sched);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `request.getHeader()` to get a *parameter* value. As its name indicates, [`getHeader()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader%28java.lang.String%29) doesn't return a parameter value, but a header value. To get a parameter value, you call... [`getParameter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks so much! Now I understand why it was doing that. I took the example for getting the headers but I edited it to take the url values  without changing the the thing you pointed out. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> String paramValue = request.getHeader(paramName);

should be

```
String paramValue = request.getParameter(paramName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getParameterMap() to get a Map object that contains your request key/value pairs.

After you have that, you can easily iterate through all the keys and get the values:

```
Map<String, String[]> paramMap = request.getParameterMap();
String[] values = null;

for (String key : paramMap.keySet().iterator()) {
  values = paramMap.get(key);
}
```

I've been away from Java for a while, so I might have the Map variable declaration wrong.